# How to plot treemap / choropleth in r ? for shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, treemap, dygraphs

I am trying to plot an interactive treemap to depict movement of inventory based on varying date input

Raw Data :

```
sraw <- structure(list(Date = c("2018-02-28", "2018-02-28", "2018-02-28", 
"2018-02-28", "2018-02-28", "2018-02-28"), Category = c("Bakery ", 
"Household ", "Household ", "Personal care", "Personal care", 
"Breakfast "), Sub_Category = c("Wafers ", "laundry ", "Pet Care", 
"Womens grooming ", "Womens grooming ", "Instant food"), Product 
= c("strawbery", 
"washing powder ", "Cat food ", "sanitary pad ", "sanitary pad ", 
"Noodles "), Brand = c("NO BRAND", "wheel ", "Whiskars", "whisper", 
"whisper", "Yipee"), Day = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), Month = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L), MRP = c("5", "48", "160", "34", "40", "45"), Quantity = c(2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Sales = c(10, 48, 160, 34, 40, 45), Wday = c("Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday"
), Week = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), X. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Date", "Category", 
"Sub_Category", "Product", "Brand", "Day", "Month", "Year", "MRP", 
"Quantity", "Sales", "Wday", "Week", "X", "X."), row.names = 870158:870163, 
class = "data.frame")
```

I have been meddling with treemap, but nothing positive on it :

```
  treeMapCoordinates <- treemapify(sraw,
                                 area = sraw$Quantity,
                                 fill = sraw$Category,
                                 label = sraw$Sub_Category,
                                 group = sraw$Category)

treeMapPlot <- ggplotify(treeMapCoordinates) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")

print(treeMapPlot)
```

but this shows error.  :

Error in treemapify(sraw, area = sraw$Quantity, fill = sraw$Category,  : 
  unused arguments (fill = sraw$Category, label = sraw$Sub_Category, group = sraw$Category)

Can anyone please assist me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have more success I think if you ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Axeman yes, I have to now, no response on the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the package was updated, and some of these functions are deprecated. You could try this instead (with your same data):

```
library(devtools)
install_github("wilkox/treemapify")
ggplot2::ggplot(sraw, ggplot2::aes(area = Quantity,
                                   fill = Category,
                                   label = Sub_Category,
                                   group = Category)) + geom_treemap()
```

This will give you the following plot:

[image]

There's no input on Shiny that you have provided or map for a choropleth.